# Merge ApplicationDbContext and DataContext into a single context

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5

I am having a problem merging these 2 contexts.

I deleted this line of code from IdentityModels.cs:

```
public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
{
    public ApplicationDbContext()
        : base("DefaultConnection")
    {

    }
}
```

I implemented this inside my DataContext.cs

```
  public class DataContext : DbContext
{
    public DataContext()
        : base("name=DefaultConnection")
    {
    }

    // Account tables
    public DbSet ApplicationUsers { get; set; }
    public DbSet Roles { get; set; }
    public DbSet Tokens { get; set; }
    public DbSet UserClaims { get; set; }
    public DbSet UserLogins { get; set; }
    public DbSet UserManagements { get; set; }
    public DbSet UserRoles { get; set; }
    public DbSet UserSecrets { get; set; }


    // App Models

    public DbSet<Course> Courses { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Student> Students { get; set; }

}
```

**Problem:**
When I "update-database" it only created the Courses and Students tables.

**Question**
If I successfully implement this method will I lose all of the nice methods that IdentityDbContext interface offers for example:

```
 var rm = new RoleManager<IdentityRole>(
            new RoleStore<IdentityRole>(new ApplicationDbContext()));
        return rm.RoleExists(name);
```

Answer (score 6):

Ok here is the solution that I found posted by Olav Nybo in this topic [How can one put application users in the same context as the rest of the objects?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19628144/how-can-one-put-application-users-in-the-same-context-as-the-rest-of-the-objects).

Go to his sample project on github: https://github.com/onybo/Asp.Net-Identity-sample-app/tree/master/CustomUser/CustomUser

Download the configurations folder from the Models folder and place the folder inside your models folder.

Inside your DataContext file you will put this snippet of code which will call these configuration files to build out your database.

```
    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        if (modelBuilder == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("modelBuilder");
               modelBuilder.Configurations.AddFromAssembly(typeof(Generic_Repo_Template.Models.Configurations.ApplicationUserConfiguration).Assembly);
    }
```

Now that your database is created you still do not have access to these tables through the datacontext object. In order to be able to access these tables through your datacontext is to include these lines of code:

```
       public virtual IDbSet<ApplicationUser> Users { get; set; }
    public virtual IDbSet<IdentityRole> Roles { get; set; }
    public virtual IDbSet<IdentityUserClaim> Claims { get; set; }
```

So the full DataContext file will look something like this:

```
public class DataContext : DbContext
{
    public DataContext()
        : base("name=DefaultConnection")
    {
    }

    // Account tables
    public virtual IDbSet<ApplicationUser> Users { get; set; }
    public virtual IDbSet<IdentityRole> Roles { get; set; }
    public virtual IDbSet<IdentityUserClaim> Claims { get; set; }

    // App Models
    public DbSet<Course> Courses { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Student> Students { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        if (modelBuilder == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("modelBuilder");
        modelBuilder.Configurations.AddFromAssembly(typeof(AspNetRoleBasedSecurity.Models.Configurations.ApplicationUserConfiguration).Assembly);
    }
}
```

Comment: To update your database from ApplicationDbContext to DataContext open your package manager and type:

Enable-Migrations -force (enter)
Add-migration (enter)
update-database (enter)

If you get an error using Add-Migration then delete all files inside your Migrations folder and try it again.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use:

`DbSet<Model> Name {get;set;}`

Instead of

```
DbSet Model {get;set;}
```

As the answer to your question. The RoleStore needs a DbContext (IdentityDbContext inherits from DbContext). So you should be able to still use the roleManager and more...