# How do I merge MVC5 Identity ApplicationDbContext into my own EF DataContext

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, entity-framework-6

My project structure consists of an ASP.Net MVC5 Web Application, and some other class libraries. I use one of those class libraries as persistence / database using Entity Framework 6 code first.

What I'd like to do is merge the MVC Identity ApplicationDbContext into my own DBContext. Not only that, but I'd like to use a custom user model.

So my context looks like this
(in seperate class lib)

```
public class DataContext : IdentityDbContext<MyUserType>
```

MyUserType looks like this

```
public class MyUserType : IdentityUser
```

I run into problems all over the shop. Ive tried refactoring IdentityConfig, Startup_Auth etc.  I've searched on here and found some articles such as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19628144/how-can-one-put-application-users-in-the-same-context-as-the-rest-of-the-objects), however these dont seem to work for me.  I've never managed to get the above architecture to work.  Does anyone know of a good online tutorial that can help specifically for MVC5 / EF6 ?

My thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

To answer my own question,  I have found that the simplest solution is to move the class ApplicationUser out of the file IdentityModel.cs in your web project, and move it to your database project.  Then have your db context inherit it.

This works well for me.  It means you have to add some MS Identity dependencies (Microsoft.AspNet.Identity,
Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework) to your database project but thats absolutely fine with me.

It also makes customising the actual user a breeze.  Just edit the ApplicationUser class to add whatever properties you like. Remember then using nuget console to add a new migration and update database.

Step 1.
Move the class ApplicationUser out of the file IdentityModel.cs in your web project, and move it to your database project. Bring in any required dependencies such as Microsoft.AspNet.Identity etc to get the project to build.

Step 2.
Change the signature of your own DbContext class thus

`public class YourDataContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>.`

Step 3.
Add a create method to your db context thus;

```
public static YourDataContext Create()
{
    return new YourDataContext();
}
```

Step 4.
In Startup_Auth.cs in your web project. Change the line

`app.CreatePerOwinContext(ApplicationDbContext.Create());`

to

`app.CreatePerOwinContext<YourDataContext>(() => YourDataContext.Create());`

Step 5.
Add any custom properties you like to ApplicationUser.cs

Step 6.
Add an EF Code first migration to reflect the above changes via nuget package manager console.

Step 7.
Update database via nuget package manager console.

The above gives you one single context that incorporates MS Identity classes and infrastructure. It also allows you to customise the user class as you wish.